# Why is my Rpc function called when I asked for my Cmd function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, client, multiplayer

Here is my problem, when I run this code as a client,

### private IEnumerator Start()

```
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            Debug.Log("je suis le serveur");
            RpcAllowTeleportation();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Je suis le client");
            CmdAllowTeleportations();
        }
    }

    [Command]
    public void CmdAllowTeleportations()
    {
        Debug.Log("C'est passé par la fonction CmdAllowTeleportation");
        if (!isLocalPlayer) { Teleportation.GetComponent<Teleport>().enabled = false; Debug.Log("cmd : it hasn't the authority"); }
        else { Debug.Log("cmd : It has the authority"); }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcAllowTeleportation()
    {

        Debug.Log("C'est passé par la fonction RpcAllowTeleportation");
        if (!hasAuthority) { Teleportation.GetComponent<Teleport>().enabled = false; Debug.Log("rpc : it hasn't the authority"); }
        else { Debug.Log("rpc : It has the authority"); }
    } ##
```

I have these logs :

[image: Mes logs]

My logs are not at all consistent with the code ! Could you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: If posting here could you use English logs? In general you should get used that coding is usually done in English and thus should be all comments and logs

Comment: 1st log : I am the client / 4th log : it went through the function RpcAllowTeleportation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `Start` is executed by **the Server** so it calls

```
RpcAllowTeleportation();
```

thus **on all clients** (so you) `RpcAllowTeleportation` is executed → you as client see the log of `RpcAllowTeleportation`.

---

Vice versa you as client do never see the log from `CmdAllowTeleportations` since it is a `[Command]` which is only executed **on the server** → Only the server will see the log of `CmdAllowTeleportations`.